# Find source of SQLserver login error

Tags: sql-server, error-handling, asp-classic

We have SQLserver2008 and the error log is filling up with these lines:

```
Login failed for user 'user1'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database. [CLIENT: xxx.xxx.xx.xxx]
```

We use user1 many places on many web-applications (classic asp). There must be some faulty password somewhere. All the applications seem to be working fine. We are getting hundreds of those messages per day.

We do know the ip-of source computer but there are thousands of classic asp-scripts. How to trace the one causing the login errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error does **not** indicate a password error.  It instead indicates that the SQL login specifies a database that the login should open, or the connection string specifies a database to open.

However, the database you're trying to open either does not exist, or the login has no permission to access the database.

**Suggested Diagnosis Procedure**

Can you open 'user1' in management studio by right clicking it and viewing its properties?  If so, on the General page, see if there is a default database specified.  Then on the User Mapping page, ensure that the login has permissions to said database.

If it does, then the connection string specifies a database to open, and User1 has no permissions or the database does not exist.

To test if the database exists without checking each and every database, you could go one-by-one through the database and give user1 db_datareader permissions until the errors stop.  **Please** don't simply assign user1 a sysadmin role to test this, since that is a real security danger.

If you cannot make the errors disappear by giving db_datareader permissions to other user databases, then the connection string is trying to open a non-existent database.

**Prevention**

I encourage you to eliminate this User1 login ASAP, and replace it with well-designed integrated security.  IIS application pools can be assigned a domain user, and those user(s) can be given SQL logins with tailored permissions.

If you cannot do that, then set up SQL logins for each web-app with tailored permissions and change those connection strings one-by-one.  The project may be laborious, but the user1 login is a serious security vulnerability, especially since you don't have control over its use at this time.

At the same time, the connection strings in a classic ASP application should be moved into global.asa and administered there so that you have one connection string (or set of connection strings) for each app, rather than individual ASP scripts all containing 1,000 redundant strings (which is what it sounds like to me).

Not trying to be preachy, but this is a problem I see **all** the time.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see how there's any other way than searching all the files for everywhere where user1 is used and compare the lines (personally if I had thousands, I'd write a program to search a folder and sub folders and return the whole string of the line the match was found on. As it's at the point of connection it makes it hard to narrow down to which script and all scripts using the same user will produce the same error.

EDIT: Actually, as you know what the password should be, you could check the line and if it doesn't contain the correct password then it's going to error.

Regards

Liam